# Automating a report in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'll start by saying I'm very new to access

I have an access database for managing calibrated equipment.

Within this there is a simple query to generate a report. you put in the cut off date and it lists all equipment who's calibration date expires by that cut off. All it does is look up the date field "date_cal_due" in a single table "main_records".

I want to automate this so that it automatically generates this report if you open the database within the first week of the month and it will automatically select the first of the following month as the cutoff date.

I can't find examples of others who have done this. So far I've created a VBA code when you open the database in "on current" that is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Day(Date) = 1 Then
DoCmd.OpenReport "due calibration"
End If
End Sub
```

I know I need to change the first line to open in the first week rather than on the first day, but initially I want to know how to automatically fill in the parameters for the report query.

I then intend to use task scheduler to automatically open the database in the first week of the month and create a VBA code on the generated report to automatically email that report to my inbox but that part's easy for me, it's automatically generating the correct report where I'm coming unstuck.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you propose to prevent sending email every day of first week?

Comment: June7 - one problem at a time. I've seen a few people have done it different ways so I'm confident that won't be too hard to do once I get this report automatically generating.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
Step by step;

1. You can go to options of your access database and then select the relevant form to open when the database file opens. Then it will hit the on_current event.
2. Create code to store the report with the relevant data.
   Here is a link how to save the report as a pdf.

https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=export-filtered-access-report-pdf-docmd-outputto

```
Public Sub ExportFilteredReportToPDF()
    
Dim reportName As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim criteria As String

reportName = "rptYourReportName"
fileName = "C:\tmp\report_export_file.pdf"
criteria = "SomeTextField = 'ABC' AND SomeNumberField = 123"
    
DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview, , criteria, acHidden
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, fileName
DoCmd.Close acReport, reportName, acSaveNo
    
End Sub
```

3. Add code that sends the pdfFile to an email adres :
   http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=758

Good luck, feel free to respond with your code in case you get stuck.

Comment: I'd use 'on open'  and certainly not 'on current'

Comment: this definitely looks like the answer I'm seeking. Can't quite get it to work though. keep getting "Run time error 2497 - The action or method requires a Report Name argument. It gets unstuck when I'm defining my criteria. I've written the line as "criteria = "Me.date_cal_due = eomonth(today(), 0) + 1"

Comment: with regard to iDevelop's comment, I originally had it set up as on open but it won't work at all then. It appears the database tries to run the code before everything has loaded in. running it on current seems to get around that.

Comment: @Thomas , could you post your entire code that you are using ?  Did you change the reportName variable to the name of your report ?